# Checking if a folder exists

Tags: filesystems, julia

I am looking for a good way of checking whether a folder exists from within a Julia script. For now what I am doing is:

```
function dir_exists(dir)
  exists = true
  try
    readdir(dir)
  catch err
    exists = false
  end
  exists
end
```

but I was wonder if there's a way that doesn't rely on exception handling.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The function is you are looking for is `isdir`.